# Problem running Blackfire together with PHP Swoole in Docker

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, swoole, blackfire

Has anyone managed to use Blackfire together with Swoole? I've been trying to set it up for a few days, but without success.

I'm calling the following script in the PHP-CLI Swoole Dockerfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# @see https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation

set -e

apt-get update
apt-get install -y gnupg --no-install-recommends

# Configure the Debian Repository
wget -q -O - https://packages.blackfire.io/gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/blackfire.list
apt-get update

# Install and Configure the Agent
echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N') $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 4)INFO$(tput sgr0) Install and Configure the Agent."
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install blackfire
blackfire agent:config --server-id=MY-SERVER-ID --server-token=MY-SERVER-TOKEN
/etc/init.d/blackfire-agent restart

# Install the PHP Probe
echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N') $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 4)INFO$(tput sgr0) Install the PHP Probe."
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install blackfire-php

# Clear
rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
mkdir -p /var/run/blackfire
```

**supervisor conf:**

```
[supervisord]
user = root

[program:blackfire-agent]
command = /usr/bin/blackfire agent:config --server-id=MY_BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID --server-
token=MY_BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN
user = root
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /proc/self/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /proc/self/fd/1
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
```

**Error msg on use blackfire curl:**

```
reginato@reginato-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15IWL:~/git/shark-tank$ docker-compose exec blackfire blackfire curl http://localhost:9501

WARNING: Some services (elk, redis) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.

20/06 00:19:26 DEBUG     blackfire Reading client configuration file "/dev/null"
20/06 00:19:26 DEBUG     blackfire Retrieving signature
20/06 00:19:26 DEBUG     blackfire Sending request GET https://blackfire.io/api/v1/collab-tokens
20/06 00:19:28 DEBUG     blackfire Sending request POST https://blackfire.io/api/v1/signing
20/06 00:19:28 DEBUG     blackfire Fetching agent credentials
20/06 00:19:28 DEBUG     blackfire Sending request GET https://blackfire.io/api/v1/agents
20/06 00:19:28 DEBUG     blackfire Timespan enabled, launching preflight.

20/06 00:19:28 DEBUG     blackfire #################] 100%
Error while running command: exit status 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but just in case someone ends up here as I did today.

Exit status returned by `blackfire curl ...` are not from blackfire but from curl.

Knowing this, the exit code 7 means:

> Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

(Here is the list of all exit codes: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

So for this specific case, the docker machine was probably not able to reach `http://localhost`.